# Set DataGridView column[0] width to fit largest text from the column?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a Datagridview which I populate, row-by-row:

```
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    string[] row = getRow();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

How can I size column 0 to fit the longest line of text from that column (across all rows)?

EDIT: I have also noticed if I manually drag the width of column 0 to the edge of my window, the horizontal scrollbar disappears, preventing me from scrolling to see the remaining columns?

Comment: Hi, why don' t you use System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode for the AutoSizeMode property of column 0

Comment: @HasanBİNBOĞA hi but I only want it applied to column 0

Comment: I mean; dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode= DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeader;

Comment: @HasanBİNBOĞA You can post this comment as an answer, this way it will be more useful for future readers. Just add some description and a link to property documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can set [`AutoSizeMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the column to one of these values: `AllCells`, `AllCellsExceptHeader`, `DisplayedCells` or `DisplayedCellsExceptHeader`. Then the column width adjusts to fit the contents of all or displayed cells in the column, including or except the header cell. For more information see [`DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnmode(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration.

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode= DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
```

Comment: I edited the answer to make it more useful for future readers.